# Is WITH better than individual OVERs in postgres?

Tags: postgresql

Just curious. If i have a big table and i need to add two aggregates of different granularity for each feature, is it less computationally intensive to first calculate all those aggregates with `WITH` tables and then join them to the original table, or add aggregate rows with `OVER` for each feature in the original tables without making new aggregate tables first?

For example if my table has:

```
year,
month,
total,
count
```

and i want to turn it into

```
year,
month,
total,
total_per_month,
total_per_year,
count,
count_per_month,
count_per_year
```

Is it better to do:

```
with
data_per_month as
(select
    year,
    month,
    sum(total) as total_per_month,
    sum(count) as count_per_month
from data
group by year, month),

data_per_year as
(select
    year,
    month,
    sum(total) as total_per_year,
    sum(count) as count_per_year
from data
group by year)

select
    year,
    month,
    total,
    total_per_month,
    total_per_year,
    count,
    count_per_month,
    count_per_year
from data as d
join data_per_month as m
    on d.year = m.year
    and d.month = m.month
join data_per_year as m
    on d.year = m.year
```

or

```
select
    year,
    month,
    total,
    sum(total) over(partition by year, month) as total_per_month,
    sum(total) over(partition by year) as total_per_year,
    count,
    sum(count) over(partition by year, month) as count_per_month,
    sum(count) over(partition by year) as count_per_year
from data
```

Comment: Use explain (analyze, verbose, buffers, settings) for both statements and see the difference

Comment: Different granularity shouldn't matter, it can still be aggregated efficiently in a single scan. I expect it would only be difficult to aggregate in different orders - but you're not using `ORDER BY` at all and also `SUM` is order-invariant.

Comment: The second version is bound to be cheaper, since it doesn't scan the table three times.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe doesn't it tho? I thought it would scan the table for each individual OVER. And I thought WITH only scans it once to group, and then scans the individual groups.

Comment: Well, test it with `EXPLAIN`.